# How to populate datefield in django admin page?

Tags: python, django

Tried the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',), 'pub_date':(datetime.now()) }
```

Which raises:

ERRORS:

```
<class 'news.admin.ArticleAdmin'>: (admin.E028) The value of 'prepopulated_fields' refers to 'pub_date', which must not be a DateTimeField, ForeignKey or ManyToManyField.
<class 'news.admin.ArticleAdmin'>: (admin.E029) The value of 'prepopulated_fields["pub_date"]' must be a list or tuple.
```

Comment: As it says in the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields), `prepopulated_fields` maps fields to other fields they are going to be populated from. `datetime.now()` is not a field. Why don't you set the default value on either database or form level?

Answer (score 1):

You were forgetting the comma for tuple.

```
from datetime import datetime
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',), 'pub_date': (datetime.now(), ) }
```

Answer (score 1):

> prepopulated_fields doesn’t accept DateTimeField, ForeignKey, nor ManyToManyField fields.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields).

Comment: It doesn't mention DateField